# Is studying system engineering valuable to software engineers?

Tags: system

I'm not sure how to put it but I just learnt about system engineering and it is about designing complex systems. It is generally oriented to manufacturing and not software companies but I was wondering if concepts and techniques of system engineering might be of help for a software engineer.

Comment: You won't create software for software companies.  You'll work for one, to create software for their customers.  Invariably involving a complex system to support their business.